# Disabling items in search (time)

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, search, crawl

When I disable a list from appearing in a search, does this:

1. Take effect immediately
2. Require a crawl
3. Take an unspecified amount of time
4. Other

I have a reference list that is appearing in search and throwing users off, I would just like to see if I need to do a crawl or not.  If a crawl is required, should it be a:

1. Full Crawl
2. Incremental Crawl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a crawl, as the item will need to be deleted from the index if it was there previously, and it's the crawler that does this.

An incremental crawl should do the trick; if you want to be super-sure and don't have that much searchable content, you could also do a full Index Reset then a full crawl.

Comment: Don't do an index reset. Just grab the individual item URLs and remove them from the index individually.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it requires performing `incremental Crawl`. it's enough to reflect your new list search settings.

**Incremental crawl covers the below scenarios,**

- Adding new document/item.
- Edit document/item Content, Properties / Delete document/item.
- Changing List / Library settings.
- Changing Item permissions.

Comment: you are welcome :)